# Which method to use to remove string characters in stringBuilder class

Tags: c#, string

I would to know, Is there any method in StringBuilder class in C#, which can remove string characters without changing other character of same value within different index?

Like for a string like "5002", what if want to remove character in first index to "3"?

I'm using StringBuilder's remove method for the specified string and it's returning me an output as "5332" instead of "5302"?

The code which I'm using to accomplish my requirement is:

```
 StringBuilder j = new StringBuilder("5002");
 Console.WriteLine(j.Replace(j.ToString(1, 1),"3");
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.chars.aspx):

```
builder[1] = '3';
```

Is that what you're after?

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("5002");
        builder[1] = '3';
        Console.WriteLine(builder); // Prints 5302
    }
}
```